# Monitoring SQL Database Activity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I deal with a 3rd party software with a client. That application has a SQL Server database I have access to. I need to figure out any cascading actions that occur to the database when I save an invoice within this software (would essentially insert into 1 table).

I have my own SQL Server that is linked to theirs, so I just need to determine any actions that occur if I were to insert into this table manually. I have looked into SQL Trace, but was curious if anyone has any input on the easiest way to find out all the actions associated with an action in this software within SQL.

Comment: [Sql Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler) is what you want to use. Keep in mind that the software might have code branches that do different actions based on conditions. Example: If you were to insert an invoice for country US then that might also trigger a branch that does X, Y, and Z but if the country is MX then A and B happen. Without fully understanding the software there might be edge cases that will never discover in your testing / investigation.

Comment: Beware - this might be a very risky path. You might be violating the license by directly manipulating this database. At the very least, you should consult with "3rd party software vendor" to see if they provide an interface to "add an invoice" in a supported manner. Typically an "invoice" is supported by at least two tables - often more. OTOH it might be trivial. Much depends on the complexity of this system.

Comment: @SMor That is not a concern.  We are already adding to the system and have full rights to do so.  The company uses the software and has rights to their own data/database.  They have an API as well which may be a better avenue but direct SQL interaction has been a better avenue in some regards and is much more simple.  In dealing with invoices, adding to this table just creates a little more complexity cause it may update other stuff dealing with the "jobs" cost in total.  But just trying to gauge the quickest solution here.

Answer (score 3):

You can't know all the implications. They may have data-driven decisions made by applications that monitor the system. That's going to be beyond the purview of any kind of internal monitoring within SQL Server.

That said, if you want to know what happens when you run your query, probably the best bet would be to capture through Extended Events. I say that over Trace because you're going to want to capture events, and [track causality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/sql-server-extended-events-sessions?view=sql-server-ver16), something Trace doesn't do. I also have a [blog post](https://www.scarydba.com/2020/01/13/causality-tracking-in-extended-events/) describing what this is and how it works.

I'd suggest you capture sql_batch_completed, rpc_completed, sp_statement_completed, sql_statement_completed. That should let you know all the queries & statements associated with your INSERT. The causality tracking will tell you the order in which they occurred and group them all together.

Comment: I would essentially want to track what happens in SQL when I perform a specific action within the software.  For my case, the users will go in and add an invoice row and "click" save.  On the surface I know that this saves an invoice row in that table but the goal would be to see data wise, what else it is updating/inserting (if anything) to see if it is viable that I can mimic that through direct insertion/updating.  So the tracking I would want to do is not necessarily from a query I would be running manually, but more so just the natural process within the application itself.

Comment: Yep. Exactly what I suggested then.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to SQL Server Management Studio to run a query on the system, you can turn on Include Actual Execution Plan on the toolbar, run the query, and examine the result.

Using code, you can do this by:

```
set statistics xml on

begin tran

insert into MyTable... -- your query goes here

rollback

set statistics xml off
```

This technique works well if the cascading actions are in some kind of trigger. The result will include the actual execution plan used when performing all cascading queries.

Unfortunately, if there is any asynchronous processing that happens after this record exists, the actual query plan will not include these events. For example, the query plan would not include the processing of SQL Broker events that were created when this row was inserted. It would also not help understand a polling processes that detects the new row and does something with it. Those processes would need to be traced using extended events or the (deprecated) SQL Profiler.